# How to run the job synchronously with sidekiq

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sidekiq, synchronous, task-queue

Currently I am working with queue job on the ruby on rail with the Sidekiq. I have 2 jobs that are depend to each other and I want 1st job to finish first before starting the 2nd job, so is there any way to make it with Sidekiq.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can use the `YourSidekiqJob.new.perform(parameters_to_the_job)` pattern. This will run your jobs in order, synchronously.

However, there are 2 things to consider here:

1. What happens if the first job fails?
2. How long does the each job run?

For #2, the pattern blocks execution for the length of time each job takes to run. If the jobs are extremely short in runtime, why use the jobs in the first place? If they're long, are you expecting the user to wait until they're done?

Alternatively, you can schedule the running of the second job as the last line in the body of the first one. You still need to account for the failure mode of job #1 or #2. Also, you need to consider that the job won't necessarily run when it's scheduled to run, due to the state of the queue at schedule time. How does this affect your business logic?

Hope this helps

--edit according to last comment

```
class SecondJob < SidekiqJob
  def perform(params)
    data = SomeData.find
    return unless data.ready?
    # do whatever you need to do with the ready data
  end
end
```

Comment: I seems get lose now, actually I have 2 jobs, one is reading the data from somewhere and the second is searching some keyword from that data. So that my second job has to wait until the data is ready. Does it is better for job scheduling or running job synchronously ?

Comment: If you schedule the jobs, you can then modify the second job to return early until data is ready. You presumably know what it means that "data is ready", so encode that as part of the second job. This way, you can run these jobs in parallel without worrying about order. Does that make sense?

Comment: Sorry, I don't get what you mean by 'modify the second job to return early until data is ready', could you please give me some detail ?

Comment: Putting the code in the answer. You should know what "data being ready" means.